# How do I make a shortcut on the desktop that automatically executes as a different user?

Tags: linux, desktop, shortcut, linux-mint

I am using Linux Mint.  I would like a shortcut on the desktop that automatically executes as a different user.

Answer (score 0):

let's assume your shortcut will list files from root. Make a .sh file like this, and you want to execute has "someuser".

su someuser -c "ls /"

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  It works but not exactly how I would like.  How do I have it run without opening two terminal windows and without this error/warning:  `Failed to connect to session manager: Failed to connect to the session manager: Authentication Rejected, reason : None of the authentication protocols specified are supported and host-based authentication failed`

Comment: Are you running a GUI with root? this is what i found http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=105850